# Armature/mesh link broken ? (worked before)

Tags: animation, armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I opened my project on another computer, and the armature won't deform the mesh anymore.

It still deforms the sub-mesh with beard and hair though...

Weight paint is still correctly painted, armature modifier correctly set, Vertex groups apparently correct too.

Any idea about that? There's no meta files that I would have forgotten to move with the .blend right?

[EDIT] I think I found a clue : the edit mode and vertex icons are greyed out on the mesh's Armature modifier.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your screenshots, the Armature modifier is disabled for View and Render. Is it on purpose ?

Comment: Oh my god, I should really get some sleep.

Thank you a lot for pointing that out, works perfectly of course.